# Git check if project folder got updated in remote since last day

Tags: git, version-control

I am working on a script to auto generate test builds for my mobile applications. The script should only generate a new build if anything in that project got updated in remote since last build.

How do I check if a specific folder/file got updated in remote?

Answer (score 0):

First, issue the following command to sync your metadata with the remote without actually changing any files:

`git remote update`

Now you can easily tell if any files have changed in the remote branch.

For instance, if you want to see if README.md has changed in origin/master:

`git diff origin/master README.md`

If the command yields no output, then the file has not changed.  If a diff is generated, then the file has indeed changed in the upstream branch.